# Is it possible to create a PLL purely in digital design, if so how?

Tags: fpga, pll, rtl

Provided that we want to reduce jitter on an a periodic input signal (square wave between 0 and Vcc) which is only in some 100 of KHz range, one possibility is to create a system purely using RTL code that shall monitor this signal and generate an output signal of almost same frequency but reduced jitter.

The input signal would be oversampled to determine frequency and an output signal shall be generated from it. Jitter shall cause the measured input signal frequency to change between successive cycles. However, the output signal frequency shall not be changed in such large steps.

Is there a weakness in this approach except that it can only work with input signals of a rather low frequency range than the system clock?

Comment: Re, "...can only work with input signals of a rather low frequency range..." A common DSP trick, when the signal of interest lies within a narrow _band_ centered on some very high frequency, is to [mix it down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer) to a lower frequency before sampling it.

Comment: How do you plan to "generate" your output signal in pure RTL?

Comment: @ThePhoton My understanding of PLL's is really vague, but doesn't it only really need to match up the zero crossings between the reference and output? If so, it doesn't necessarily need a sine wave and you could use square waves.

Comment: @DKNguyen, one component of a PLL is a VCO. I don't know any way to make a VCO in pure RTL HDL.

Comment: @ThePhoton Hmmm. yeah. I guess what the OP is not really talking about a PLL but just some kind of step-wise (because digital) frequency averager/re-transmitter that runs off a much faster and lower jitter clock.

Comment: @ThePhoton you use an NCO, which is only a few lines of HDL.

Comment: You can think of input signal as a square wave. It represents a type of clock signal which is used to time activity of certain parts of a system. Its frequency shall be 100s of kHz atmost.

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity.  I believe your "input periodic" is "periodic input signal".

Comment: Are the signals in question square, sinusoidal, or something else?

Comment: Square wave. Going into the FPGA. The problem is that the input signal has a massive jitter which has a bad impact on the system performance. The question is how to take this 100s of kHz of jitter signal and create another signal with almost no jitter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely possible. It is called an all digital PLL. Instead of a VCO, you use a numerically controlled oscillator, or NCO. An NCO is basically just a counter, called a phase accumulator, that you add some value to on each clock cycle, called the phase step. You then use one or more of the MSBs as the output. You could use the MSB to get a square wave, or you could use several MSBs to get a sawtooth wave or index into a lookup table for a sinewave. Add a digital phase detector and PID controller, and you have an all digital PLL.

The all digital PLL works the same way as a normal one. You don't need to measure the frequency, all you need to do is measure the phase difference and close the loop with a properly tuned PID controller, and the control loop will hunt for and lock on to the correct frequency on its own. You might want to enforce some limits to the NCO adjustment range, though. If you use all "power of two" gains in your PID loop, then you won't even need any multipliers and you can do everything with just adders.

Now, the downside of all digital PLLs is that you're not going to be able to get the jitter down below one clock period of whatever clock frequency you're running at, for obvious reasons. If your design can tolerate that, then you're good to go. Otherwise you'll need a proper analog PLL.

Comment: Also often called a "software PLL" when implemented in software rather than dedicated digital logic.